# How do I send shift+down using winapi c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, keyboard

Using the following code

```
Sleep(3000);
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_DOWN, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_DOWN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

I expect windows to select a line of text if i place my cursor in an editor during the sleep (hence it is foreground window)

However this just moves the cursor down a line.

Using the following works but surely this isn't the way its supposed to be done.

```
Sleep(3000);
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
keybd_event(VK_DOWN, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_DOWN, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP | KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY, 0);
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, 0, 0);
keybd_event(VK_SHIFT, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
```

It appears by using the KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY flag I can hold it down for the arrow key. But no matter how I try to release it doesn't work. But I can press and release it normally to clear the held shift key.

Comment: `keybd_event()` is deprecated, use [`SendInput()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/winuser/nf-winuser-sendinput) instead, passing it an array of inputs to send at one time (don't call it with `cInputs=1`, as most newbies are prone to do)

Comment: If you wish to implement higher-level concepts (like selecting a line of text), using low-level input faking isn't going to be reliable. Use [UI Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/winauto/entry-uiauto-win32).

Comment: @RemyLebeau I have. The behaviour is the same in the simple case demonstrated.